# Is malloc(sizeof(char[length])) incorrect?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, malloc

When I dynamically allocate an array in C++, I use the following:

```cpp
char* arr = new char[length];
```

So naturally, when I started learning C, I have been using the following to allocate my strings:

```c
char* arr = malloc(sizeof(char[length]));
```

However, I see that common practice is to use the following instead:

```c
char* arr = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
```

Are the statements above equivalent, or is there some reason I should not use `sizeof(char[length])`?

Comment: I'd have to stop and wonder whether that would result in 4 or 8 bytes (size of a char* pointer) instead of the buffer size that you're expecting, so to me it is less clear.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`, so it's redundant.

Comment: _"When I dynamically allocate an array in C++, I use the following:"_ - Then you will be stopped in your tracks for your next job.

Comment: I'd recommend door # 3: `arr = malloc(sizeof arr[0] * length)` and avoid trying to match the type in sizing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two are effectively the same.

`sizeof(char[length])` evaluates to the size in bytes of an array of `char` of length `length`.  This is the same value as `length * sizeof(char)`.

While the latter is more common, the former is fine as well.  The only caveat is that some compilers, i.e. MSVC, don't support variable length arrays in which case `sizeof(char[length])` would be invalid.